# How to disable text box when checkox is checked in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have check box array and 2 groups of text box array like this.

```
//CHECKBOXES
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="male" name="sex[0]">
<input type="checkbox" value="female" name="sex[1]">
<input type="checkbox" value="others" name="sex[2]">
</div>

//TEXTBOXES1
<input type="text" name="numberofheads[0]" disabled="true">
<input type="text" name="numberofheads[1]" disabled="true">
<input type="text" name="numberofheads[2]" disabled="true">

//TEXTBOXES2
<input type="text" name="average[0]" disabled="true">
<input type="text" name="average[1]" disabled="true">
<input type="text" name="average[2]" disabled="true">
```

If I check male sex, all the text box that has `0` key will be enabled, and if unchecked, it will be disabled again. is it possible to do this in jquery? if it does please help me.. thanks!

Comment: ofcourse it is possible but what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it http://jsfiddle.net/df6qjf2j/.

```
$(function() {
    $('[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var number = $(this).index();
        $('[name="numberofheads[' + number + ']"]').attr('disabled', !isChecked);
        $('[name="average[' + number + ']"]').attr('disabled', !isChecked);
    });
});
```

Comment: wow this codes works fine but, is there a way something like this $('input:checkbox[name="sex"]') than $('[type="checkbox"]')? i tried it but it doesn't get the index.

Comment: here we used type=checkbox,because all input have same type.if you want to use by name you have to write all name like this:  $('[name="sex[0]"],[name="sex[1]"],[name="sex[2]"]') http://jsfiddle.net/1wc6wwr8/2/

Comment: @p3ac3, try `$('[name^="sex"]')`

Comment: @Mr7-itsurdeveloper i want to select it by name because i have many checkbox array in my DOM.

Comment: @dizel3d +1 Great.I always try to learn new things here:-$('[name^="sex"]').

Comment: @p3ac3 Then its ok.You want this functionality on these checkboxs only.

Comment: @Mr7-itsurdeveloper yup!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 //or $("input[type='checkbox']") use this 

$('[name="sex[0]"],[name="sex[1]"],[name="sex[2]"]').click(function(){
        var numberval = $(this).index();

 if($(this).is(':checked'))
  { 

  $("input[name='average["+numberval+"]'],input[name='numberofheads["+numberval+"]']").removeAttr('disabled');

   }   

  else
  {
          $("input[name='numberofheads["+numberval+"]'],input[name='average["+numberval+"]']").attr('disabled',true);

   }

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1wc6wwr8/2/